# Program keeps giving me an attribute error: 'int' has no attribute 'upper'

Tags: python, attributeerror

I'm trying to make a simple code which takes the user input and adds it to a list. I want the user to input scores until they press "Q" to quit. For some reason, it thinks that my userInput is a string, when it's not. Every time a user puts in a number, I want it to convert that input into an integer. But it won't let me do that because it "can't have an 'upper'. I've done this before on another program, so I don't know why it won't let me now. Here's my code:

```
def main():
    list1= []
    userInput= input("Please enter an integer between 0 and 10: ")
    amountOfscoresEntered= 0
    while userInput.upper() != "Q":
        userInput= int(userInput)
        amountOfscoresEntered= amountOfscoresEntered + 1
        if userInput < 0 or userInput > 10:
            print("Invalid Input")
        else:
            list1.append(userInput)
            totalNumofPointsearned= sum(list1)
main()
```

Comment: Inside your while loop you are doing this: `int(userInput)`. So, you are casting your `userInput` to an `int`. As the error is stating, `int` does not have an `upper` method. The `upper` method is a *string* method.

Comment: Also, it seems like that code is going to go on forever. `userInput` will never be "Q" inside your `while` loop.

Comment: To clarify: the first time when you enter the `while` loop, `userInput` is indeed a string, but after that, it is an `int`. Since you never change `userInput`, your while loop will never exit, and `userInput` remains an `int`. You'll want an `input()` function inside your while loop as well, near the end.

Comment: Yes, but I want that input to change into an int. I want the program to change userInput into an integer if userInput does not equal "Q".

Comment: then assign result to different variable ie. `input_number = int(userInput)`

Comment: I want the program to terminate once the user inputs "Q". The only reason I put a .upper on userInput is so that way the user can either use a lower or uppercase "Q", and it still works.

Answer (score 1):

As the last line of your while loop, add

`userInput= input("Please enter an integer between 0 and 10: ")`

This should solve your problem.

You are using a `while` loop and giving a condition to break it when the user inputs a letter Q. Which means that you want the user to keep giving multiple inputs. So far, in your program it only takes user input just once. Therefore, on the second iteration of the while loop, it'll check the condition `userInput.upper() != "Q"` with a variable you casted to an `int`. This is where you get your error. By adding a line to take another user input to the end of the loop should fix your problem.

Answer (score 1):

On each iteration of your while loop, your casting `userInput` to an integer. The integer type does not have the attribute `.upper()`, so Python raises an error accordingly.

A better way to accomplish your goal, would be to make use of a `while True` loop instead. That way, you avoid testing the user input in your while loop, and allow yourself to use `.upper()`:

```
def main():
    list1 = []
    amountOfscoresEntered = 0

    while True: # use while true instead

        # get user input repeatedly
        userInput = input("Please enter an integer between 0 and 10: ")

        # lets check the user input
        # before we cast it to an integer.
        if userInput.upper() == "Q": 
            break

        elif 0 < int(userInput) < 10:
            print("Invalid Input")

        else:
            # once we have verified that
            # our input is what we want,
            # we can cast `userInput` to
            # an integer, and add it to
            # `list1`.
            list1.append(int(userInput))
            amountOfscoresEntered += 1

    totalNumofPointsearned = sum(list1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Think about this for a moment. At the line

```
userInput= input("Please enter an integer between 0 and 10: ") # input always gives string, even if they enter a number.
```

If your user enters the string '10' (because the input() method always gives you a string) then the first thing your while loop does is try to make it upper case

```
while userInput.upper() != "Q":
```

So, what does an upper case '10' look like?

Answer (score 0):

Try using a variable for the condition of the loop and then make the loop false when

```
if userInput.isalpha(): 
    if userInput.upper() == "Q": 
        running = False
```

Answer (score 0):

I have few things to note before providing the solution you are looking for.

1. In terms of style, please stay consistent throughout your code for readability.
2. Python version: Depending on the version of python you are using you may or may not encounter errors of this sort.

   input() --> python2.x does not interpret letters nicely. It converts then into a variable and tries to interpret them. Therefore, causing your program to fail.

   raw_input() --> actually takes the input and allows you to do anything you want to it.
3. Fixed code:

   ```
   def main():
      list1 = []
      amountOfScoresEntered = 0
      totalNumOfPointsEarned = 0
      userInput= raw_input("Please enter an integer between 0 and 10: ")
      while str(userInput).upper()!="Q":

           amountOfScoresEntered= amountOfScoresEntered + 1

           if int(userInput) < 0 and int(userInput) > 10:
               print("Invalid Input")
           else:
               list1.append(userInput)
               totalNumofPointsEarned= sum(list1)

           userInput= raw_input("Please enter an integer between 0 and 10: ")
   main()
   ```
4. [input() and raw_input() reference](http://www.python-course.eu/input.php)
5. [Input and Output](http://anh.cs.luc.edu/python/hands-on/3.1/handsonHtml/io.html)
6. [raw_input()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input)

Answer (score 0):

User input has be inside the while loop and have to use try block to catch the exceptions accordingly. since upper() cannot used with integers,have used both 'Q' and 'q' for the validation separately.

Working code:

```
def main():
list1 = []
amountOfscoresEntered = 0
totalNumofPointsearned=0
while True:
    userInput = input("Please enter an integer between 0 and 10: ")
    try:
        if userInput == "Q" or userInput == 'q':
            break
        elif not userInput.isalpha() and not int(userInput) < 0 and not int(userInput) >10:
            userInput = int(userInput)
            amountOfscoresEntered = amountOfscoresEntered + 1
            list1.append(userInput)
            totalNumofPointsearned = sum(list1)
        else:
            print("Invalid Input")
    except ValueError:
            print ('Invalid Input')
return amountOfscoresEntered, totalNumofPointsearned


if __name__ == '__main__':
    attempt, total_point_earned = main()
    print('Number of Attempts=%s \nTotal Points Earned=%s' %(attempt,total_point_earned))
```

Comment: Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue